# Download sources for AWS Lambda from external source systems

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I need to create simple terraform infrastructure and part of this infrastructure needs to create AWS Lambda with java Spring Boot application as source code.

I read [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html) related to lambda and looks like right now terraform can only load sources from [local file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html#filename) or from [s3 bucket](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html#s3_bucket). In my case I store application jar file in Nexus repository(binary storage) and want to load source code/jar during Lambda creation from Nexus too.

Based on terraform documentation it has:

- [local provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/index.html) that could only create files.
- [http provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/http/index.html) that supports responses with Content-Type `text/* or application/json` and in my case I have `application/java-archive`
- [external provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/index.html) expects json response and in my case I have archive.

no one of this approaches solve my problem. Of cause I can create bash file that will run `wget` command for jar file and then run terraform command. But this does not look pretty from my perspective.
May be you can suggest any other solutions that would be more accurate and flexible.

Comment: How about using s3 as maven repository instead of nexus repository? This will solve your problem with publishing your artifact your central private repository and using the s3 url of your artifact for your aws lambda in cloudformation/terraform template.

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale, good point, but unfortunately I work for a company with some strict rules related to binary resource storage. And no one will let me to store some jars on s3 while other teams will continue to store libs in nexus

Comment: Okay. I get that. It will be worth to check with AWS support team.

Comment: What if terraform script would starts downloading file from your repo and re-upload it on s3? If TF has not a provider you could use AWS CLI command. I don't know TF but this shuld be a simple commabd execution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is the one you have already suggested - wrap terraform in a parent command that first fetches the jar file - or even just document this as a required manual step / dependency. I believe this is fairly common.

Alternatively, if you really want to be provided with something for which there is no existing provider, you can [create your own Terraform provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/plugins/provider.html).